# Don't understand how to plot my dataframe in a Sankey diagram

Tags: python, pandas, plotly, sankey-diagram

I'm trying to use plotly to plot a sankey diagram of how my customers move between sales buckets each week. Right now, my dataframe looks like this:

```
account_id |    week    | sales_bucket
     1     | 2019-06-10 |   $0-20
     1     | 2019-06-17 |   $21-40
     1     | 2019-06-24 |   $0-20
     2     | 2019-06-10 |   $40-60
     2     | 2019-06-17 |   $40-60
     3     | 2019-06-17 |   $60-80
     4     | 2019-06-10 |   $40-60
```

Essentially I want to track if customers are moving into higher buckets week over week. But not every customer makes a transaction every week, and of course there are new customers every week as well. I'm having trouble wrapping my head around how I can quickly get my dataframe into the `source-sink-count` structure that plotly requires from the dataframe that I have above.

Comment: Look at: https://plot.ly/python/sankey-diagram/

Comment: Yes, I've looked there. All of the examples start with the datafram in the `source-sink-count` structure, which mine is not in. That's the part I'm having trouble with; getting my dataframe from its current structure to that structure.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that yours links should be something like:

```
label = [
  "Week 1 - Bucket 1", 
  "Week 1 - Bucket 2", 
  "Week 1 - Bucket 3", 
  "Week 2 - Bucket 1", 
  ...
  ]
```

Then `source` and `target` (flow from **source label to target label** index) are in principle:

```
source = [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, ...]
target = [3, 4, 5, 3, 4, 5, 3, 4, 5, ...]
```

The last bit is to calculate the weights in the links. For that you can use `group_by` and `agg` from `pandas`:

```
value = df.groupby(['Week', 'Sales Bucket'])['Id'].agg('sum').values.flatten()
```